# Dynamic resize Canvas; keep image on position

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

Is there a way to create a dynamic canvas which gets the same dimensions as the `<div>` it is in.

I tried it with `height: 100%, width: 100%` in the CSS of canvas. Than I have a canvas always as bif as the div **BUT** the content inside it scales to.

So I'd like to know a way to resize the canvas but keep the exact position of the image even if i change the landscape on mobile for example.

Comment: yes, but set the width and height attributes of the canvas element, not the css width and height. Those will stretch the canvas element, whereas the width and height attributes will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the width and height *attributes* of the canvas element, not the css width and height which only stretch the canvas, which defaults to 300x150 width/height. You can dynamically size the canvas element with JavaScript.

Here is a working example.

```js
//get the elements
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const myDiv = document.getElementById("my-div");

//set the width and height attributes to the div width and height
function resize(){
  canvas.width = myDiv.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = myDiv.clientHeight;
}
//on page resize, call resize()
window.addEventListener("resize", resize, false);

//call resize() initially to set the canvas size correctly
resize();

//you can call resize() when your div changes size, dynamically resizing the canvas to the div
```

```css
div {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
canvas {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: so a huge thanks. it did the trick! I would be even more thankful i've you would have an idea for the image. right now it changes position to but i would like it to stay in the top right corner (for example) even if i change the landscape.

Comment: set the css `position: fixed` or `absolute` on the image element, and then set `top: 0` and `right: 0` to keep it in the top right corner of the page. bear in mind fixed and absolute positioning are similar but different.

Answer (score 0):

For resizing canvas you can use HTML5 canvas tag. Below skeleton is everything you need for an app that needs a resizable canvas. It:

1. Adds HTML markup for a canvas element with a unique ID (‘c’ in this example)
2. Declares a Javascript variable named htmlCanvas with a reference to that canvas’s ID using the DOM’s getElementById() method
3. Gets a graphics context to draw on (the variable named context)
4. Calls a user-defined function called initialize() in this example that gets access to the browser’s resize event
5. Which creates an implicit loop, calling the user-defined resizeCanvas() method when the browser window changes size

Example Code:

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Resize HTML5 canvas dynamically</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            border: 0;
            overflow: hidden; /*  Disable scrollbars */
            display: block;  /* No floating content on sides */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id='c' style = 'position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;' >
    </canvas>
    <script>
        (function() {
            var 
                // Obtain a reference to the canvas element
                // using its id.
                htmlCanvas = document.getElementById('c'),

                // Obtain a graphics context on the
                // canvas element for drawing.
                context = htmlCanvas.getContext('2d');

            // Start listening to resize events and
            // draw canvas.
            initialize();
            function initialize() {
                // Register an event listener to
                // call the resizeCanvas() function each time 
                // the window is resized.
                window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

                // Draw canvas border for the first time.
                resizeCanvas();
            }

            // Display custom canvas.
            // In this case it's a blue, 5 pixel border that 
            // resizes along with the browser window.                   
            function redraw() {
                context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
                context.lineWidth = '5';
                context.strokeRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            }

            // Runs each time the DOM window resize event fires.
            // Resets the canvas dimensions to match window,
            // then draws the new borders accordingly.
            function resizeCanvas() {
                htmlCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                htmlCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
                redraw();
            }

        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you will want to use the div clientWidth and Height, not just the window.innerWidth / Height